# How to send text to the username and password field within the webpage throug Safari Browser and selenium-webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, safaridriver, webdriverwait

I am trying to login to the webpage for which I am supposed to write test scripts. But the login script fails each time in Safari, although the same script runs well on Chrome.

Error message displayed:

```
Sep 10, 2018 10:55:06 AM org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions findElement
WARNING: WebDriverException thrown by findElement(By.id: mfacode)
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:05:20.749Z'
System info: host: 'iMac.localdomain', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:1c2b:a0b9:a043:3a94%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.6', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver
Capabilities {applicationCacheEnabled: true, browserName: safari, cleanSession: true, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: true, handlesAlerts: true, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: false, nativeEvents: true, platform: MAC, platformName: MAC, rotatable: false, version: 13605.3.8, webStorageEnabled: true}
Session ID: E2219A59-8EEE-4380-93B6-77A7DDE289BE
*** Element info: {Using=id, value=mfacode}
```

The script I am using:
public class LoginSafari {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.safari.driver", "/usr/bin/safaridriver");
    WebDriver driver= new SafariDriver(); 
    driver.get("https://yapiapp.io/welcome");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("auth0-lock-input"))).sendKeys("alaka.goswami@*****.com");
    driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("*******");
    driver.findElement(By.className("auth0-lock-submit")).click();
    // WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 40);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);    
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("******")));
    // username and password masked//
```

Is there any way to get passed this or solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
Sep 10, 2018 10:55:06 AM org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions findElement
WARNING: WebDriverException thrown by findElement(By.id: mfacode)
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

...implies that the **WebDriver** instance was unable to find any element as per the [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) you have used.

You need to take care of a couple of things as follows:

- Different browser renders the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) different so you need to construct *Locator Strategies* to work *Cross Browser*.
- As the *username/email* and *your password* field both are on the same page you have to induce *WebDriverWait* only once.
- As you need to invoke `sendKeys()` method so instead of *ExpectedConditions* as `visibilityOfElementLocated()` you need to use the **`elementToBeClickable()`** method.
- Your effective code block will be:

  ```
  import org.openqa.selenium.By;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

  public class yapiapp_login {

      public static void main(String[] args) {
          System.setProperty("webdriver.safari.driver", "/usr/bin/safaridriver");
          WebDriver driver = new SafariDriver();
          driver.manage().window().maximize();
          driver.get("https://yapiapp.io/welcome");
          new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input.auth0-lock-input[name='username  ']"))).sendKeys("alaka.goswami@*****.com");
          driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.auth0-lock-input[name='password']")).sendKeys("Alakananda Goswami");
      }
  }
  ```
- Browser Snapshot(with GeckoDriver/Firefox):

[image: yapi_login]